# Find the values of t, where=10 in v=11/2(1-cos((PI/4)*t))

Tags: calculus

The vertical speed v (in m s^(-1)) of a lift through its lift shaft varies over time t (in s) in accordance with the equation

v=11/2 (1-cos⁡(π/4 t) )
for 0≤t≤8.

Determine the values of t for which v=10.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Is it $$v=\frac{11}{2}\left(1-\cos\left(\frac{\pi}{4}t\right)\right)$$?

Answer (score 0):

When finding all solutions of equations of the form

$$ \cos(\alpha t)=x $$

you can make use of the $\arccos$ function a unit circle diagram of the equation:

[image: unit circle diagram]